# formalize in predicate logic: All students join some course that they don't like.

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, logic-translation

I came up with two formulas and have no Idea whether their correct.
1. ∀x(S(x)∧¬C(x))
2. ∀x∃y(S(x)∧C(y)→DoesNotLike(x,y))

And then I have one a bit more complicated, that I can think of multiple ways how to formalize but have no way of knowing if correctly:
Every student attends a class taught by a teacher that they dont like.

P.s. this is not my homework, just preparation for an exam.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify carefully what you're taking the predicates $\ S\ $ and $\ C\ $ to mean.

Presumably, $\ S\left(x\right)\ $ means "$\ x\ $ is a student".  I think your first formulation would then be synonymous with the sentence given in the title if $\ C\left(x\right)\ $ were taken to mean "$\ x\ $ likes all courses he or she has ever joined, or will ever join", and the conjunction were to be replaced with implication:$^{\mathbf \dagger}$
$$
\forall x\left(S\left(x\right)\rightarrow \neg C\left(x\right)\right)
$$
However, I can't think of any interpretation of $\ C\left(y\right)\ $ that would make your second formulation similarly synonymous with that sentence.

It looks like $\ C\left(y\right)\ $ in the second formulation was intended to mean "$\ y\ $ is a course", but if that were so, there wouldn't appear to be anything in that formulation to specify that the course $\ y\ $ is one that student $\ x\ $ has joined or will join at some time.  This could be partly rectified by making $\ C\ $ a two-place predicate for which $\ C\left(x,y\right)\ $ means "$\ y\ $ is a course which $\ x\ $ has joined or will join at some time", but even that's not enough to make the second formulation synonymous with the target sentence.

A second problem with the second formulation is the placement of the predicate $\ C\ $ before, rather than after, the implication.$^{\mathbf *}$  As written, the sentence
$$
\forall x\exists y\left( S\left(x\right) \wedge C\left(x,y\right)\rightarrow\mbox{DoesNotLike}\left(x,y\right)\right)
$$
merely says that for every student there is some course that the student *wouldn't* like *if* he or she were to join it.  It does *not* assert that every student *will*, in fact, join such a course at some time.  This can be rectified by placing the predicate $\ C\ $ after the $\mbox{implication:}^{\mathbf *}$
$$
\forall x\left( S\left(x\right) \rightarrow\exists y\left( C\left(x,y\right)\wedge\mbox{DoesNotLike}\left(x,y\right)\right)\right)\ \ .
$$
As now formulated the predicate $\ C\ $ represents an existential statement which could be further spelt out by putting $\ C\left(x,y\right) = \exists t\,J\left(x,y,t\right)\ $, where $\ J\left(x,y,t\right)\ $ is taken to mean "$\ y\ $ is a course which $\ x\ $ joined, or will join, at time $\ t\ $. The last formulation above would then become:
$$
\forall x \left( S\left(x\right) \rightarrow\exists y\exists t\left( J\left(x,y,t\right)\wedge\mbox{DoesNotLike}\left(x,y\right)\right)\right)\ \ .
$$

*** Edit:** Thanks to [Daniel Schepler](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/337888/daniel-schepler), in his comment below, for pointing out an error in my original attempt to rectify this deficiency.

$\mathbf\dagger$ **Further edit:** I forgot that the first formulation suffered from the same problem as my first attempted rectification of the second.

Comment: Should you also change $S(x) \wedge \cdots$ to $S(x) \rightarrow \cdots$ so the statement doesn't require that *everything* in the domain of discourse (including also each course - unless you're using a multi-sorted logic) is a student?

Comment: Yes, of course you're right.  I have now amended the answer.